# ResNet Model Incorrectly Predicting One Class when Loaded into Flask Web App? Not matching Saved Model Predictions

Tags: tensorflow, flask, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

I have used ResNet50 transfer learning to train a model for image classification of 5 categories. It has 90% test accuracy. I save the model as .h5. I am trying to deploy the model to a Flask Web App using load_model, but when I do so, the model accuracy is not the same. There is a whole [thread](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4875) of 3+ yrs with this similar issue and no guaranteed solution so I am providing issues I think are specific to my case.. I have tried many things and the best attempt I have been able to find works well for 4/5 categories, but then the 5th category performs terribly... Like it doesn't seem trained at all only on that category. I have been told that it may be the preprocessing pipeline and that I should make sure that the image that flask is giving the model when uploaded to the website is the same as the way the model has been trained. The image array values include negative values in the preprocessed saved model, but are all positive values in the flask web app. So I might be on to something there, but just can't quite figure it out.

Here is my ResNet50 saved model:

```
manual_variable_initialization(True)

os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'
np.random.seed(70)
random.seed(70)
tf.random.set_seed(70)

filepath = "saved_models/weights-improvement-{epoch:-2d}-{loss:.2f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode = 'min')
log_csv = CSVLogger('my_logs.csv', separator=',', append = False)
callbacks_list = [checkpoint, log_csv]

img_height, img_width = (224,224)
batch_size = 32

train_data_dir = r"preprocessed_images_scraped/train"
valid_data_dir = r"preprocessed_images_scraped/val"
test_data_dir = r"preprocessed_images_scraped/test"


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
    width_shift_range= 0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    fill_mode="nearest",
    brightness_range=[0.9,1.1],
    rotation_range =30,
    vertical_flip = True,
    validation_split = 0.05,
    rescale=1./255)


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size = (img_height, img_width),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    subset='training') #set as training data

valid_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    valid_data_dir, #same directory as training data
    target_size = (img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode= 'categorical',
    subset='validation') #set as validation data

test_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_data_dir, #same directory as training data
    target_size = (img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=1,
    class_mode= 'categorical',
    subset='validation') #set as validation data

x,y = test_generator.next()
x.shape

base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
predictions = Dense(train_generator.num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = True

model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_generator, epochs = 90, verbose=1, validation_data = valid_generator, callbacks=callbacks_list)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_generator, verbose=2)
print('\nTest Accuracy:', test_acc)

model.save_weights('saved_models/resnet1_aug')
model.save('saved_models/resnet1_aug.h5')
model.save('saved_models/resnet1_aug.hdf5')
```

Here is the web Flask app page, predict_app.py :

```
app = Flask(__name__)

def get_model():
    global model
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('resnet1_aug.h5')
    print(" * Model loaded!")

def preprocess_image(image, target_size):
    if image.mode != "RGB":
        image = image.convert("RGB")
    image = image.resize(target_size)
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    image = image / 255.0
    print(image)
    return image

print(" * Loading Keras model...")
get_model()

@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    message = request.get_json(force=True)
    encoded = message['image']
    decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    processed_image = preprocess_image(image, target_size=(224, 224))
    prediction = model.predict(processed_image).tolist()
    print(prediction)

    response = {
        'prediction': {
            'category1': prediction[0][0],
            'category2': prediction[0][1],
            'category3': prediction[0][2],
            'category4': prediction[0][3],
            'category5': prediction[0][4]
        }
    }
    return jsonify(response)
```

The preprocessed images from the ResNet model seem to output negative values from imagedatagenerator, whereas the array values of the images in the Flask app are always positive. So maybe some solution lies here:

ResNet model preprocessed image (print(image)) with negative values:

```
Category: [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
[[[-0.05466276  0.3498863   0.09145098]
  [-0.05074119  0.3498863   0.09145098]
  [-0.04681962  0.3498863   0.09145098]
  ...
  [-0.3644667  -0.27756473 -0.363451  ]
  [-0.36054513 -0.29717258 -0.37129414]
  [-0.37230983 -0.30893728 -0.37913728]]

 [[-0.04681962  0.3498863   0.12282354]
  [-0.05466276  0.34596473  0.11105883]
  [-0.05858433  0.34596473  0.09929413]
  ...
  [-0.3644667  -0.2814863  -0.363451  ]
  [-0.3644667  -0.30109414 -0.3752157 ]
  [-0.37230983 -0.30893728 -0.37913728]]

 [[ 0.01200391  0.22047453  0.1149804 ]
  [-0.00368236  0.2636118   0.1267451 ]
  [-0.01936864  0.3106706   0.14635295]
  ...
  [-0.3644667  -0.2814863  -0.36737257]
  [-0.3644667  -0.3050157  -0.3752157 ]
  [-0.36838827 -0.30893728 -0.37913728]]

 ...

 [[ 0.00808234  0.07929805 -0.14384314]
  [ 0.00416077  0.07537648 -0.14384314]
  [ 0.00416077  0.07537648 -0.14384314]
  ...
  [-0.39583924 -0.4187412  -0.4497255 ]
  [-0.39583924 -0.41481963 -0.4497255 ]
  [-0.3997608  -0.42266276 -0.45364708]]

 [[ 0.01200391  0.09498432 -0.13992158]
  [ 0.01200391  0.09498432 -0.136     ]
  [ 0.01200391  0.09498432 -0.136     ]
  ...
  [-0.40368238 -0.42266276 -0.4497255 ]
  [-0.40760395 -0.42266276 -0.45756865]
  [-0.40760395 -0.42266276 -0.45756865]]

 [[-0.00368236  0.1106706  -0.10462746]
  [ 0.00416077  0.1106706  -0.1124706 ]
  [ 0.00808234  0.10282746 -0.12815687]
  ...
  [-0.40760395 -0.41089806 -0.4497255 ]
  [-0.40760395 -0.42266276 -0.4497255 ]
  [-0.40368238 -0.42266276 -0.45364708]]]
```

Flask web app image array with all positive values (note this is not the same image as above):

```
[[[[0.15686275 0.17254902 0.05098039]
   [0.15294118 0.17254902 0.05098039]
   [0.15686275 0.16862746 0.04705882]
   ...
   [0.20392157 0.18039216 0.13333334]
   [0.10980392 0.07450981 0.05098039]
   [0.09411765 0.05490196 0.03137255]]

  [[0.16078432 0.1764706  0.05098039]
   [0.16078432 0.1764706  0.05098039]
   [0.15686275 0.17254902 0.04705882]
   ...
   [0.38431373 0.3529412  0.2       ]
   [0.16470589 0.11764706 0.07450981]
   [0.12156863 0.09019608 0.05882353]]

  [[0.16078432 0.18039216 0.05098039]
   [0.16078432 0.1764706  0.05098039]
   [0.15686275 0.1764706  0.05098039]
   ...
   [0.68235296 0.7176471  0.4117647 ]
   [0.38039216 0.34901962 0.18431373]
   [0.18431373 0.14117648 0.08235294]]

  ...

  [[0.7490196  0.7372549  0.35686275]
   [0.6862745  0.6862745  0.32941177]
   [0.6039216  0.6039216  0.2901961 ]
   ...
   [0.47843137 0.34117648 0.09019608]
   [0.49803922 0.3529412  0.09019608]
   [0.5137255  0.36862746 0.10196079]]

  [[0.7058824  0.69803923 0.34117648]
   [0.627451   0.6313726  0.3137255 ]
   [0.52156866 0.5294118  0.25882354]
   ...
   [0.5568628  0.4117647  0.1254902 ]
   [0.57254905 0.42352942 0.12941177]
   [0.58431375 0.43529412 0.13725491]]

  [[0.64705884 0.64705884 0.31764707]
   [0.54901963 0.5568628  0.27450982]
   [0.42745098 0.42352942 0.21568628]
   ...
   [0.6117647  0.46666667 0.16078432]
   [0.627451   0.48235294 0.16470589]
   [0.6392157  0.49411765 0.1764706 ]]]]

Prediction: [[0.003161849919706583, 0.0021534611005336046, 0.9830918908119202, 0.005027933977544308, 0.006564896088093519]]
```

Lastly, here is the predict.html page. Though I do not think the issue should lie here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>deeplizard predict image app</title>
    <style>
        * {
            font-size:30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>    
    <input id="image-selector" type="file">    
    <button id="predict-button">Predict</button>
    <p style="font-weight:bold">Predictions</p>    
    <p>Category 1: <span id="category1-prediction"></span></p>
    <p>Category 2: <span id="category2-prediction"></span></p>
    <p>Category 3: <span id="category3-prediction"></span></p>
    <p>Category 4: <span id="category4-prediction"></span></p>
    <p>Category 5: <span id="category5-prediction"></span></p>
    <img id="selected-image" src="" width="224" height="224" alt=""/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let base64Image;
        $("#image-selector").change(function() {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                let dataURL = reader.result;
                $('#selected-image').attr("src", dataURL);
                base64Image = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "");
                console.log(base64Image);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL($("#image-selector")[0].files[0]);
            $("#category1-prediction").text("");
            $("#category2-prediction").text("");
            $("#category3-prediction").text("");
            $("#category4-prediction").text("");
            $("#category5-prediction").text("");
        });

        $("#predict-button").click(function(){
            let message = {
                image: base64Image
            }
            console.log(message);
            $.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict", JSON.stringify(message), function(response){
                $("#category1-prediction").text(response.prediction.category1.toFixed(6));
                $("#category2-prediction").text(response.prediction.category2.toFixed(6));
                $("#category3-prediction").text(response.prediction.category3.toFixed(6));
                $("#category4-prediction").text(response.prediction.category4.toFixed(6));
                $("#category5-prediction").text(response.prediction.category5.toFixed(6));
                console.log(response);
            });
        });       
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "*There is a whole thread with this issue.*" - so, please either post a link, or remove the reference altogether.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4875) There has not been a verified or universal solution after 3 years. I tried to provide details that are specific to my situation. If you want to dive into the 300 comments there, then be my guest. I have worked through just about all of them before posting here btw :)

Comment: I don't want to be your guest really. What I said was just - either it is relevant (in which case you should post the link) or it is not (in which case you don't mention it at all); your call. But mentioning "a thread" w/o link does not make any sense.